# How do I setup an alarm for CloudFront from CloudWatch in a CloudFormation yaml template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I want to setup an alarm in case an error occurs on CloudFront from CloudWatch.

In the console, I would directly create an alarm that would send me an email in case the `TotalErrorRate` is larger than 0. This is working fine.

But now I want to setup the same setting in a yaml template file in CloudFormation. I have trouble figuring out the right values for the corresponding parameters. My file currently looks like this:

```
  # CloudWatch
  CloudFrontTotalErrorRateAlarm:
    Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
    Properties:
      ActionsEnabled: Boolean
      AlarmActions:
        - String
      AlarmDescription: "Trigers an alarm if there is any error (e.g. 4xx,5xx)"
      AlarmName: "MyApiTotalErrorRate"
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      Dimensions:
        - Dimension
      EvaluationPeriods: "1"
      ExtendedStatistic: String
      InsufficientDataActions:
        - String
      MetricName: TotalErrorRate
      Namespace: AWS/CloudFront
      OKActions:
        - String
      Period: 60
      Statistic: String
      Threshold: 0
      TreatMissingData: String
      Unit: String
```

For some parameters, I could figure out what the actual value could be. But for others I essentially don't know what I should put in so that AWS would send me an email in case an error occurs. The following parameters are missing values:

- `ActionsEnabled`
- `AlarmActions`
- `Dimensions`
- `ExtendedStatistic`
- `InsufficientDataActions`
- `OKActions`
- `Statistic`
- `TreatMissingData`
- `Unit`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you need to create an `SNS Topic` with your email address as one subscriber:

```
EscalationTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic

EscalationTopicEmailSubscriber:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: john.doe@example.com
      Protocol: email
      TopicArn: !Ref EscalationTopic
```

As a second step you need to provide the `DistributionId` to the CF template (as long as the Distribution is not part of the CF template):

```
Parameters:
  DistributionId:
    Type: String
```

In the end you have to plug everything together and configure the `CloudWatch Alarm` in the following way:

```
CloudFrontTotalErrorRateAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    Namespace: AWS/CloudFront
    MetricName: TotalErrorRate
    Dimensions:
      - Name: DistributionId
        Value: !Ref DistributionId
    Statistic: Sum
    Period: 60
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
    Threshold: 1
    AlarmActions:
      - !Ref EscalationTopic
```

The "final" CF template could look like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  DistributionId:
    Type: String
Resources:
  EscalationTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic

  EscalationTopicEmailSubscriber:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
      Properties:
        Endpoint: john.doe@example.com
        Protocol: email
        TopicArn: !Ref EscalationTopic

  CloudFrontTotalErrorRateAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      Namespace: AWS/CloudFront
      MetricName: TotalErrorRate
      Dimensions:
        - Name: DistributionId
          Value: !Ref DistributionId
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: 60
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Threshold: 1
      AlarmActions:
        - !Ref EscalationTopic
```

Comment: I got this error: `User  is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreateTopic on resource(Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError`. Do I have to add a policy? If so where?

Comment: It seems that you as a user doesnt have the permission to do that.

Comment: How can I change it? I would want to make the change of the permission in cloudFormation. Is that possible?

Comment: You have to ask the account owner to grant your account the permissions to do that.

Comment: If my question answered your initial question please mark it as "Answered".

Comment: I first need to check regarding the permission, whether it works or not.

Comment: Anything new here?

Comment: Why do I need the distributionId? How do I get the value for the key distributionId?

Comment: Helped me the answer

Comment: In Dimensions, I had to add Name: Region Value: Global